# Sending Python File Storage Type to Google Drive

Tags: python, flask, google-drive-api

i am new in the world of programming and python. I have a small flask app that consists of a form that ask users to upload a certain document. That document i then store into a variable in my python script called

```
file_upload = request.files['filename']
```

I want to send this same file storage into a folder i have in google drive.

The problem i am having is that every tutorial that i see is uploading files from a path in their computers, but i havent seen one that doesnt use a folder path.

(btw i am using GOOGLE APP ENGINE which doesnt allow me to store the file first to a directory and then to google drive)

Comment: You need a path to the file on the machine that the code is running on.  In this case the file would need to be stored on app engine.

Comment: but i tried to save the file to a directory and it says that the directory doesnt exist but it does...what i am trying now is to create a tmp dir, save tje file, execute drive api and then delete the tmp dir.....not sure if it will work

Comment: what i have read is that you cant save to a filesystem in google app engine

Comment: I beleave that is true yes.

Comment: i found a way using blobstore....although i still would like to use drive...but at least its something hehe